# Find $y$ such that $A-yB \geq 0$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider $M=A-yB$ where $A$ is real, symmetric, positive definite, $B$ is real, symmetric, positive semi-definite, and $y$ is a positive scalar variable. I am interested in maximum value of $y$ for which $M$ is positive semi-definite. I've seen in some papers that they split $M$ into smaller matrices as
\begin{equation}
M=\sum_{i} (A_i-y_iB_i)
\end{equation}
then they find $y_i$'s for small matrices and choose $max(y_i)$ as the answer. I'm just wondering under what condition can we do this? Small matrices $M_i$ can overlap with each other.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Assume $B\ne0$. Take $x\ne0$.
You have
$$
x^T(A-yB)x \ge x^TAx - y x^TBx \ge (\lambda_{min}(A) - y \lambda_{max}(B)) \|x\|^2,
$$
this gives immediately that for
$$
y\le \frac{\lambda_{min}(A)}{\lambda_{max}(B)}
$$
the matrix $A-yB$ is positive semi-definite. The bound is sharp, if there is a vector that is both eigenvector of $A$ to $\lambda_{min}(A)$ and eigenvector of $B$ to $\lambda_{max}(B)$.

This discussion can be repeated for those small matrices, of course. Hope this helps.